# Naming convention and %20

Tags: sharepoint-online, tasks, sharepoint-library, display-name

I'm having a bit of a debate with someone. We are creating Tasks and Libraries within SharePoint 2013. They don't want to have to use underscores or CamelCase in order to name Tasks or Libraries. However, I think it's in good form to do so.

Is it my imagination, or does the %20 cause issues within a web URL when emailing it to someone. I seem to remember it caused issues with me. Is not that not one of the reasons to use underscores or CamelCase?

Thanks

Comment: dont use spaces for url name. simple as that. I wouldn't say it causes issues, it's just a bad practice. you can have whatever you want as the *title*

Answer (score 5):

It isn't really an issue either way, but the preferred approach is to create a list or library like "ChangeRequests' then after it is created, rename it to "Change Requests". Emailing a link shouldn't cause problems, the browser will handle it correctly.

It is really more of a personal preference than anything, but CAML casing it makes it easier to read in most cases.

The same thing goes for creating new columns in lists and libraries but that is more so for making development life easier.

Comment: According to Eric

Comment: different strokes for different folks, there is no hardfast rule about this, meaning it is probably opinion based

Comment: I could have sworn there were issues with the %20 in URLs that were emailed to me. I will go along with what my coworkers want.  I wish they would just adhere to what Sharepoint suggests.

Comment: @Eric you might add explicitly that this approach will leave the URL as the CamelCase form while making the name as displayed on the page have a space.